# Python Robot Invalid Return From Keyword usage

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to execute following code in Robot and getting below error.
I am having hard time figuring out whats wrong

```
${job_id}=    Run Keyword And Return If    "${cur_build}" != "<my_Build>"    perform software upgrade    ${wd}    <device_name>    <my_build>
```

Below is the xml output.

```
Success:  0   Failed :  0   Skipped :  0
 Stop  Delete</msg>
<status status="PASS" endtime="20160602 02:22:51.590" starttime="20160602 02:22:10.415"></status>
</kw>
<msg timestamp="20160602 02:22:51.591" level="INFO">Returning from the enclosing user keyword.</msg>
<status status="PASS" endtime="20160602 02:22:51.591" starttime="20160602 02:22:10.413"></status>

</kw>
<tags>
<tag>draft</tag>
<tag>upgrade</tag>
</tags>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20160602 02:22:51.592" critical="yes" starttime="20160602 02:21:01.560">Invalid 'Return From Keyword' usage.</status>
```

**EDIT**

So I understand that Run Keyword and Return if can only be used in Keywords and not in Testcase. But then how would I do something like below in a Test Case

```
if <some_cond>:
   ${my_var}=    <Keyword A>
   Keyword B=    ${my_var}
```

One way could be to add define new keywords with but is there a way to do that inside a testcase without defining anynew keyword

Comment: Your question is not clear enough please provide some more information, like the code used to interpret .robot file.

Comment: The line of code you posted must be inside a user keyword. It cannot be in a test case, setup, or teardown. See http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Return%20From%20Keyword

Comment: @ombre42 Okay I understand that now.

Comment: Is it resolved now? were you asking "How to run a keyword, based on condition and store the return value? " without defining new keyword?

Comment: @Waman I understand now why  I was getting the  so my problem is stll there but yes the problem statement is now changed and its now what you have mentioned.

Comment: Saurabh I had used Set Variable If keyword to set a variable when condition is true. As per your newest edit, do you need to send ${my_var} as argument to Keyword B?

Comment: @anukalp yes I need to send $my_var as argument to Keyword B

Comment: @anukalp can you show me your example of set variable if. The problem I was having with set variable is that I was not able to set variable with return value of keyword

Comment: ${answer}= | Set Variable If | @{list_of_integers}[${index}]==$find_this_var | ${index} | ${0}. Variable ${answer} is set to ${index} or 0. We cannot execute a keyword after set variable, you'll have to use a combination of Set Variable If and Run Keyword If.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if below code serves your purpose

```
*** Variables ***
@{list1}          @{EMPTY}
@{list2}          This    is    list    list1

*** Test Cases ***
Conditional Test Case1
    ${flag}=    Set Variable If    @{list1}!=@{EMPTY}    ${true}    ${false}
    ${rc}=    Run Keyword If    ${flag}==${true}    Log Multiple Values    ${list1}
    ${rc}=    Run Keyword Unless    ${flag}==${false}    Log Multiple Values    ${rc}

Contitional Test Case2
    ${flag}=    Evaluate    len(${list2}) is not None
    ${rc}=    Run Keyword If    ${flag} == ${true}    Log Multiple Values    ${list2}

*** Keywords ***
Log Multiple Values
    [Arguments]    @{list_args}
    [Documentation]    This keyword logs its arguments and also returns them
    Log Many    @{list_args}
    [Return]    @{list_args}
```

Comment: `${rc}=    Run Keyword If    ${flag}==${true}    Log Multiple Values    ${list1}`
If ${rc} will hot the return value of Log Multiple Values then this is what I was looking for.